# 5 tags is too few

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there a tag limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34732/why-is-there-a-tag-limit)

There should be 7 at least.

Comment: Yet you only used two...

Comment: Why not 11?  Turn it up to Eleven!!!

Comment: OMG! UNLIMITED POST LENGTHS AND UNLIMITED NUMBER OF TAGS! GREAT IDEA!

Comment: Why you got to hate on only 5 tags? Were not all rich.

Comment: I can see *possibly* upping it on Meta, but for the other sites, 5 seems plenty.

Comment: I think that he has a point but failed to motivate his opinion on this. I found out in several cases that more than 5 tags are required to define a question. Think that usually one tag is for the language, one for the OS. Having a limit is great but this should be more than 5, probably 7.

Comment: `[If] [this] [is] [implemented], [it] [will] [become] [my] [hobby] [to] [ask] [questions] [with] [nothing] [in] [the] [body] [and] [the] [entire] [question] [spelled] [out] [in] [tags].`

Answer (score 16):

Quick analysis of the public data dump to look at the usage of tags in existing questions reveals the following numbers for questions having N tags:

```
N  Questions
1  24926
2  58744
3  73071
4  51859
5  33955
```

Here's a graph:

[alt text http://img229.imageshack.us/img229/6284/tagcounts.png](http://img229.imageshack.us/img229/6284/tagcounts.png)

The graph looks similar to a normal distribution.  It may have a long tail off to the right, suggesting larger numbers of tags might be utilized, but my opinion is that **5 is a sufficient maximum**, since the most common number of tags used is 3.

Comment: Science! http://imgs.xkcd.com/store/imgs/stand_back_square_0.png

Comment: Ah, but is it 3 because we're limited to 5? Does the limit change the stats?

Comment: I would expect that if we really needed more tags, then the median would cluster around 4-5.  Instead it clusters around 2-3.  I don't see how a limit of 5 makes people more likely to choose 2 or 3 tags.

Comment: @Adam, because they want to leave room for future expansion.

Comment: @devinb - I suppose that's possible.  The data is just data, it's open to interpretation.  I still like mine, though. :)

Comment: I would like to point out that on Meta, you really have only 3 or 4 tags to use however you want. ( *3 if a moderator adds a **`[status-*]`** tag* )

Comment: I really dislike *let's stick to the median* mentality. This way there would have never been any Stack Overflow to begin with. You want to keep any society in stagnation - give them statistics and democracy :)

Comment: Interesting theory.  Again, of course the data itself does not suggest a tag limit.  I was very careful to state that this is my opinion of how to interpret the data.  As for stagnation... I'm not sure that forbidding statistics and democracy will get you very far either. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that 5 Tags is Okay for 99% of the cases. For example, if I tag my Post "c#" I usually do not need to tag it "c#3.0" unless it really is specifically about C# 3.0, but even then, "C#" is good enough.

At least in my opinion, I found that the 1 or 2 most "prominent" tags for a question are good enough. Unless you really need to write a C# Extension function to SQL Server that has to communicate with an Oracle database over XML using Java as a Proxy, but even that fits in 5 tags (mssql c# oracle java xml).

Answer (score 2):

If you can't accurately sum up the subject matter of your question using 5 tags, then you (and others) must be doing something wrong. I can't think of very many times where I have had to use all 5 tags.

StackOverflow example:

If I am asking a question about how to do something with extending the collections class in ASP.NET I may tag it:

"ASP.NET", "VB", "Collections" "Extending"

And even then I would probably not include "extending" because it on itself isn't a very useful tag (and I would probably mention extending the class somewhere in my title).

If you are still finding that you are using too many tags, you should probably look at simplifying the question until it reaches a certain granularity. Asking a question that is too big and encompasses too many areas at one time is a good way to not get your question answered well by the people.

Comment: It's for this reason that I bloody hate the `join` tag.

Comment: Paraphrasing; If you can't accurately sum up the meaning of life in one short sentence then you (and others) must be doing something wrong... BTW Have you stopped beating your wife? **Yes** or **No** - you **don't need more** than one word to answer this simple question, do you? :)

Answer (score 1):

Is your real name, Roget?

5 tags is plenty if you actually know what your problem is about or at least what platform you're on about. Any more than that and you're throwing about tags just for the sake of trying to spread the net of eyeballs.

Comment: What is your real name *random*, 13?

Comment: rand() for short, mt_rand() if you want to be formal about it.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I needed more than 5 tags was when I was asking about [video comparisons](https://superuser.com/questions/15884/hdmi-versus-component-versus-vga-versus-dvi) on SuperUser.
[video comparisons](https://superuser.com/questions/15884/hdmi-versus-component-versus-vga-versus-dvi)

I ended up adjusting my question, but I would have liked to have added component video in to the question.

Other than that one exception, I've found I've never used 5 before.

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be a good argument to be made to increase the number of tags here on Meta.

After all, you have to choose one of the required tags. Also if a moderator adds one of the `[status-*]` tags, that leaves only 3 tags to use as you like.