# What is up with the waffle fetish?

Tags: discussion, meta, fun, waffles

Setting aside the fact that waffles were created in the seventh circle of hell, cause suffering and apocalyptic horror wherever they are witnessed, and are instruments of pure evil, where did the obsession with talking about them in every thread arise?

Can we stop this and have more waffles?

Also, will waffles.stackexchange.com exist?

And even more importantly...do ponies like waffles? Do waffles like ponies? Are there such things as waffle-flavored ponies and pony-flavored waffles?

Comment: And please.... no 80-comment mini-series on the art of flour-based snacks.

Comment: must... get... edit privs...

Comment: These waffle-sympathizers keep conflicting with my edits!

Comment: Wow, you guys are having lots of editing fun.

Comment: Can we close this now as a dupe of the meme question?

Comment: I just looked at the edit history. John Rasch: You're on notice.

Comment: I had waffles today. They were yummy. And Belgian.

Comment: Good thing to live in Beligum then!

Comment: I used to have a job where I sat on a particular surface and got WAFFLEBUTT

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)

Comment: @Tim this is an old time Meta meme, MSO is new so they have no clue about it in there. Don't think it should be migrated away.

Comment: I just google about Stack Overflow and Waffles, found this here. Tried waffles.stackexchange.com amd...
"The Q&A site waffles.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…yet."
Yet? Oh godwhythepainthewaffles

Comment: @Peter Setting aside the pointlessness of copy-editing a years-old closed post, the sentence you changed read "waffles were..., cause..., and are...", which already had the verbs agreeing with each other.

Comment: _**WAFFLES!!!!!!!!!!**_

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[image: Keyboard waffles]

Comment: Hell yeah keyboard waffles!

Comment: Oh... *baby*...

Comment: I saw those waffles and then I http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pXfHLUlZf4

Comment: That's awesome.

Comment: WANT           .

Comment: CTRL + ALT + EAT

Comment: @Eric: you saw those waffles and then you were not available in your country‽

Comment: I just saw this image in the 404-error page and wanted to post a bug-report about it ... the waffle was obviously not made this way by this machine, but turned around before being photographed. (Look at the position of the return and shift/capslock keys, and the space bar). Could we have a correct image?

Comment: @paulo it's an art project as I recall.. http://www.treehugger.com/files/2007/05/my_type_of_appl.php "Designed by Chris Dimino as part of a group exhibit for the School of Visual Arts, the typewriter iron represents the best of reinvention: an obsolete product, minimally modified, is given a completely new function."

Comment: Yeah, I found the link to http://www.designhead.net/cdimino/ on the 404-page. (The image is there hidden behind the second icon in the second line of "Design", then the fourth image page. They have also other things made from typewriters.) It still annoys me that they did turn the waffle for the photo.

Comment: Are those QWERTY waffles?

Comment: Woke up real sleepy but had to work. Oh dang, I just poured syrup on my keyboard.

Comment: http://s239.photobucket.com/user/co-pirate/media/star-wars-and-waffles-fetish.jpg.html; see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138012/246931

Comment: Cupcake approves of these waffles +1

Comment: [waffles.stackexchange.com](//waffles.stackexchange.com) should *totally* redirect to this answer.

Comment: @JohnRasch Where is the EAT Key?

Answer (score 36):

What waffle fetish?

Comment: Do you like ponies @waffles? Do ponies like @waffles? More importantly, are you yummy? Are you a mutant waffle?

Answer (score 24):

I truly wish I knew... then; maybe it is best not to.

I even somehow got labelled a waffle-hater; pah.

---

I'm torn between closing this question as noise, and adding it to the FAQ...

Comment: I think you can turn back public opinion on this. Photo-ops of you + waffles. Prove yourself to be a staunch anti-pancaker.

Comment: Good lord. I am tired of Marc's pro pancake, anti waffle stance.

Comment: @Marc: Well certainly you shouldn't ban anyone for a day for discussing waffles **this** time, right?

Comment: I'm never going to here the end of this, am I... for the last time **it had nothing nothing to do with waffles**.

Comment: why do you hate

Answer (score 19):

Waffles! I **love** waffles. One day, back when Stack Overflow was still young, I was making delicious pecan waffles and testing something on the site. I needed filler for a dozen or so quick posts, and used the recipe for waffles. [They're long gone now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143927/what-is-the-purpose-of-uservoice), but I still get a pleasant yearning for waffles, golden crispy waffles, *drenched* in Real Butter and Smokey Maple Syrup, whenever I visit Stack Overflow.

I would assume that anyone else mentioning waffles has similarly good taste.

Answer (score 17):

It's just [another mini-meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480/295232) that has taken MSO over. Waffles...and ponies.

Comment: Even as the originator of many SO/MSO memes, I am finding it hard to keep track of them all. I think we need to start chronicling this information in the hallowed FAQs

Comment: Waffles and ponies? That sound like a tasty combination.

Comment: @Marc: You're on notice

Answer (score 10):

1. I *love* waffles. I had some this morning for breakfast. Effing delicious, man.
2. [It](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/5-tags-is-too-few/13915#13915) was in response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/5-tags-is-too-few), which wasn't a question at all. The OP made an assertion without any backing, so I stated my opinion with as much backing. I needed to make the 15 characters, so I said, "You know what, I'm going to spread my love of waffles." And so I have.
3. Also, waffles.

Comment: Hell yeah waffles.

Comment: 1) Waffles / 2) ??? / 3) Profit!

Comment: +1 for Waffle Gnomes

Answer (score 8):

It was originally [started by Eric](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19480#19480), then from a deleted post, it was latched onto by others.

Comment: Eric began the waffle meme long before that.

Comment: Thanks for the correct attribution

Comment: Corrections made.

Answer (score 4):

I can't wait until I have sufficient reputation points to move all of these waffle questions to Super User where they clearly belong.

There we can have endless questions about the best waffle iron (clearly the [Waring Pro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009K3SY)), spatulas, butter versus margarine and all the various possible syrup combinations (Vermont Grade A Dark Amber FTW).

Comment: Butter & Grade B for that awesome richness!

Comment: @Shog9 - I find Grade B overwhelms any fruit which may be placed on top

Comment: @Rob: You need better fruit. The flavor of perfectly ripe Palisade peaches meld beautifully with the caramelly goodness of Grade B.

Comment: @Shog9: I'll have to try that some time.

Answer (score 4):

I saw waffles this morning at my local grocery store, thought of this thread/mem/Eric, and took a picture.  (We don't get many waffles in these here parts.)

Spooky.

[alt text http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/stack-overflow-waffles.jpg](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/stack-overflow-waffles.jpg)

Note how Waffle is spelled *Waffel*.  Someone here on MSO mocked my spelling of Waffle once, and know we know why...

Comment: Know we know and now we know no?

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

It's because Waffle House is the only place open when devs are awake.

Comment: I can attest to many nights of this, maybe you're onto something

Comment: I hear that Reapers hang out there too...

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly instigated by a flock of Belgians.