# A Stack Overflow brick in the Computer History Museum wall

Tags: discussion, status-completed, donation

I'm thinking stackoverflow.com llc / inc should buy a brick in the [Computer History Museum Wall](http://www.computerhistory.org/contribute/impression/).

It's for a noble cause -- the CHM is one of my favorite places on the planet, and the money is a non-profit donation in support of their effort to record the history of the computer.

The brick I am looking at is the **Terabyte**:

> The wall will consist of a series of permanent high-tech plaques engraved with your message. Honor your favorite computer pioneer, recall your first technology project, or annotate any technology memory you wish to commemorate in this special area. Each engraved wall plaque will be placed in the newly remodeled entry area of the Museum, ensuring that your reminiscences will be preserved and shared for years to come.
>
> - Name: Terabyte
> - Price: $5000
> - Description: 8" x 8" Plaque
> - Max Lines of Text: 6
> - Max Characters per Line: 18
> - Company logo or Stock Symbol available

<s>So, then, the question: **what should our CHM plaque say?**</s>

Completed, selection made public, and payment confirmed with the Museum: [Our Brick in the Computer History Museum Wall](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/our-brick-in-the-computer-history-museum-wall/). Now we wait for October to see it live!

Comment: If you can put the APL character set on a brick, I bet you could reimplement SO in APL and it'd fit on that brick....

Comment: Have you verified that both the 108 characters *and* the logo can be accommodated? Or will someone need to do a graphic that includes the logo and some text (then the character limit may be different - higher or lower - depending on the resolution of the engraving technology)? Is there additional cost for the logo?

Comment: I think the museum should *donate* this brick to you because 17,210 meta users are going to visit the museum just to see *this* brick.

Comment: I took me five answers to realize that the first row of numbers were only coordinates, not actual text for the brick.

Comment: I can think of one company that would be so much happier if their brick could hold seven lines of 20 characters.

Comment: @Dennis - and that would be... ?

Comment: It might be just me, but it feels kinda like buying your own hand print tile at the walk of fame.

Comment: @George: If you do the math, the result might have a familiar ring to it.

Comment: I really can't read a question with the words "brick in the (...) wall" without having that same song stuck in my head for the rest of the day.

Comment: @Dennis - ah. I get it now. :)

Comment: The museum doesn't twit

Comment: Whatever the answer, I think it should include the 123456789012345678 numbers on it.. even if we lose a column and a row. And it must be monospaced font.

Comment: Why nobody ever thought of [Bricky Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)? `'); DROP TABLE bricks;--` (in two lines, obviously). Oh I see, [historical incongruence](http://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php?title=327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom&action=history).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 Dedicated to the 
3 expert programmers
4 whose tireless
5 work made this
6 brick possible.
```

Stack Overflow Plaque at CHM

Prototype: ( [Source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/our-brick-in-the-computer-history-museum-wall/) )

[image]

Picture:

[image: Stack Overflow Plaque at CHM]

Comment: Aw. I liked a lot others more(even being serious) :(

Comment: meta is a fine place for in-jokes, but I think when you're putting words on granite (literally or metaphorically) in a public place, it's best to play it straight, simple, and clear.

Comment: This one really stands out. If possible, I'd suggest a slight change so that the dedication is directed to the *expert programmers* rather than their *tireless work* : `3 expert programmers`, `4 whose tireless`, `5 work made this`.

Comment: Congratulations, I don't think it could possibly be more vanilla.

Comment: @ben good idea -- done!

Comment: @Mehrdad To be honest, I don't think that's a very flattering picture of the plaque

Comment: @Yi Unfortunately, it's difficult to take a photo of a reflective surface, especially when all you have is a crappy iPhone 4 camera. It's better than nothing though. Feel free to replace with a better one! By the way, you have to go upstairs to see "the wall". There's nothing else upstairs. Nobody goes there and for some unknown reasons, I felt the staff were not exactly happy about us going there. In fact, after I came down, they put a barrier ribbon to prevent people from going there. I was a bit uncomfortable about this and just wanted to take a picture ASAP and come back.

Comment: @mehr this is awesome, thank you! I believe the museum is not fully 'done' with the work, the big opening is Jan 31st

Comment: @Jeff You're welcome. Thank you for putting it there! I didn't know about the "big opening." Everywhere I saw, they mentioned last week as opening. I would've gone on the 31st if I knew it :(

Comment: Now can we have the closed as dupe brick?

Answer (score 180):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com 
2
3  closed as exact
4    duplicate of
5  brick #13379001
6
```

Comment: +1 You'd need two bricks, then.

Comment: Precisely. The second brick would redirect to the first, of course.

Comment: @Julian H. Lam: Nope, the second brick has been moved to meta.

Comment: First one to make my LOL!

Comment: Isn't it sad you think of closing questions when you think of SO?

Comment: I think it's great that there is so much knowledge on the SO-family that 50% of questions can be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @Gnoupi that statement tells me the real issue is question discoverability.

Comment: To discover, you have bring up the effort to search first, though.

Comment: @ongle: Discoverability is sometimes an issue, but at least as often it seems to be users who `[don't know how|are unwilling]` to search. First time is free, of course, but after that folks should take some responsibility.

Comment: Way to hijack an answer's comment thread by discussing totally off-topic usability issues :-P

Comment: @Andy I will require (pinky in mouth) 1 Million Dollars before I will return your comment thread.

Comment: what is `9001`?

Comment: @eSKAy: IT'S OVER NINE THOUSAAAAAAND!

Comment: @DrJokepu: what is over nine thousand?

Comment: @eSKay: The power level, of course

Comment: @DrJokepu: power level of whatt??

Comment: @eSKay: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiMHTK15Pik

Comment: So, StackOverflow is PHP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379001/1204143

Answer (score 121):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 
3 How do I move the
4  turtle in LOGO? 
5 
6
```

Comment: this is GENIUS!

Comment: How do I move the brick in MUSEUM?

Comment: __That__ is the question.

Comment: Seems a bit narcissistic to me.

Comment: @raven - As opposed to buying a $5000 brick to commemorate yourself, which is totally humble.

Comment: @Length The brick is to commemorate the community, not any particular person.

Answer (score 118):

```
  123456789012345678
1 See:
2 http://meta.
3  stackoverflow
4   .com/
5    questions/46920 
6 for brick history
```

Comment: I just love this one!

Comment: I'm not too excited about this one - the link is only valid for so long.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.

Comment: @George, what is going to happen to the link?  Surely Jeff is doing backups...

Comment: What if the backups fail?

Comment: @George: What if the museum collapses?  What if Atlantis rises from the ocean tomorrow and marauding merpeople reduce us to the stone age again?  Gotta draw the line somewhere....

Comment: @Pop: I'm just saying... what happens 50 years from now when people come to the museum? The joke will mean nothing if the URL is invalid. Who knows if the Internet will even exist?

Comment: @George: I have come from the future to find out what these URLs that you refer to are. We find them in some archeological artifacts that we have dated to approximately this period.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Good one ;)

Answer (score 109):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2  \ji
3  /.((( 
4 (,/"(((__,--.
5    \  ) _( /{ 
6    !|| " :||
```

Comment: +1 "My Little Pony, My Little Pony; What does the future hold?"

Comment: @waiwia Oh! I was wondering why if the SO logo had gotten a little tipsy or something...

Comment: They would engrave it in non-monospace font. :)

Comment: OMG, Unicorn(s)!  Oh wait, that's what my name is stuck at over on SO, but not here.

Comment: This is my favourite, but I don't think the font on the brick will do justice to this masterpiece :-)

Comment: It looks like a poodle wearing a unicorn mask. (`"` = eyes)

Answer (score 103):

Kicking things off with my dumb suggestion.

Remember the brick is **6 lines of 18 characters!**

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 our VC asked us to
3 build a business 
4 but we spent all 
5 their money on
6 this brick instead
```

Comment: If you go this route, why stop with just 1 brick?

Comment: @jon that would be funnier -- a whole wall, 1 letter per brick, heh.

Comment: Can I buy the one under yours and put "that is one expensive brick!"?

Comment: If you write it this way, you can avoid the hyphenated busin-ess: `| StackOverflow.com | Our VC asked us to | build a business, | but we spent | all their money on | this brick. |`

Comment: @robert excellent, I reformatted it per your suggestion

Comment: 7 -- Burma Shave.

Answer (score 78):

```
  123456789012345678
1 to ask questions 
2 is human, 
3 but 
4 to provide
5 expert answers is
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: For some reason reminds me of a slightly less sinister version of the motto from The Prisoner: http://i41.tinypic.com/b6udzk.png

Comment: I resent this one. Stop excluding us 'free rider'-'question-askers'-'only 5 rep per upvote' users!

Comment: Nice!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Consider a version of this except with "to provide *expert* answers."

Comment: @ripper I took robert's advice and amended *free* to *expert*

Comment: I think it would be better without the "but". Like: "To ask questions/is human./To provide/expert answers is/stackoverflow.com". (And one line to spare.)

Comment: @Arjan, but that completely screws up the cool way the text currently looks :)

Comment: @Earlz, given [the official examples](http://www.computerhistory.org/contribute/impression/images/wall_plaques_big.jpg) I wouldn't rely on the looks... (And I'm not natively English, but the *but* actually seems *wrong* to me. Maybe *and* is better?)

Comment: Is that an evil EE reference?

Comment: @Jeff - you misunderstood me. I was, half jokingly, protesting against exclusion of great question askers. Asking great questions should not be excluded (although yes, the _purpose_ is the answers ... but without great questions there can't be great answers ... or at least "answers to great questions". This comment will now self-terminate).

Comment: a bit marketing-y

Answer (score 71):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com:
2 The only place
3 where you can get
4 100 answers
5 for what to write
6 on this brick.
```

Comment: make that 38 now...

Comment: Just to make it that much more geeky, it should be 42.

Comment: I think it should be the *actual* final # of answers.

Comment: That'd be a good meta brick.

Comment: Are there dynamic bricks?

Comment: The only way to get an accurate count would be to lock the question before engraving ;-)

Comment: @RobertCartaino  99 answers so far!

Answer (score 68):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 None of us
3 Is as Dumb
4 As all of Us
5 -Jeff Atwood & 
6  Joel Spolsky
```

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us.html

Comment: hmm, initially misread that as "none of us is as dumb as Jeff Atwood & Joel Spolsky"

Comment: That's already the subtitle for the 'Meetings' demotivational poster. Still funny though. I think of this everytime I'm in a meeting at work... or really *anywhere* for that matter.

Answer (score 56):

Poetized version of Atwood's [earlier answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46920/a-stack-overflow-brick-in-the-computer-history-museum-wall/46922#46922).

Answered questions quick
VCs made wallets thick
Won some cash to kick some ass
But spent it on this brick.

```
  123456789012345678
1 Answered questions
2 quick, VCs made
3 wallets thick, Won
4 some cash to kick
5 some ass but spent
6 it on this brick
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [sampsonresume.com](http://sampsonresume.com/labs/stackoverflow/so-brick.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Yo! The Beastie Boys are in the house!

Comment: it has no meter. rhythm fail.

Comment: Sounds like it rhymes pretty well to me - perhaps it's the char-per-line restriction that is making it difficult to read?

Comment: "rhythm" != "rhyme". but yeah, splitting the lines differently helps.

Answer (score 45):

```
  123456789012345678
1 Programming Q&A?
2 StackOverflow.com
3 has both.
4 -- Answered 2009
5 community briki
6 Jeff Atwood
```

Comment: I confess. I only posted this to get the community briki joke in.

Comment: well, I LOL'ed so mission accomplished. COMMUNITY BRIKI!

Comment: I confess.  I only upvoted this because the `community briki` joke was in.

Answer (score 41):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 Asking 14-million
3 expert programmers
4 what to write
5 on this brick.
6 [status-completed]
```

*Of course, we'll need the actual # of users.*

Comment: @Robert the tag is [status-completed] (which fits in 18 characters) not [status-complete]

Comment: fixed (and here's the filler to meet minimum comment size requirements).

Comment: Imho the best one ever

Comment: Where does the figure of 14-million come from? (The most recent SO user id is 319,402.)

Comment: @Arjan - Made it up. Need to know the number of unique *visitors* to the site; *way* more than 319K.

Comment: I think I should clarify why this brick is the best.  It contains a reference that SO is a great and influential Q&A site.  It also contains a generic joke, in addition to an inside joke; this is what many bricks here lack.

Comment: I really like it. We can get it, but anyone can enjoy it.

Answer (score 38):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2
3 [closed]brick
4 
5 not programming
6 related
```

Answer (score 30):

```
 123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow() {
2   ask_questions;
3   get_answers;
4   rep++;
5   return profit;
6 }
```

Comment: Bill adds ()s to all of those...

Comment: line 5 should read "return profit;"

Comment: @doekman: Thanks for the bug report. [status-completed].

Comment: -1 for using a language that requires semi-colons.

Comment: postincrement => not good

Comment: I think `return stackoverflow()` actually. Then there it will be a stack overflow (unless you've got tail recursion).

Comment: Line 5 should not be reachable.

Comment: @Paul: Why not? I profit from the answers I receive, even if only intellectually. Besides "profit" is a meme.

Comment: profit is undefined

Comment: Why not `return stackoverflow()`?

Answer (score 30):

It really should be something in code . . . and this seems like the most obvious choice:

```
  123456789012345678
1 /* See:
2  StackOverflow.com
3 */
4 public int Foo() {
5     return Foo();
6 }
```

Because of course the logical place that someone would come to figure out what that means, or how to fix it is to visit [StackOverflow.com](http://StackOverflow.com/).

Comment: That's seven lines.

Comment: @Dennis, could just take the `{` up a line and reduce it to 6. This is actually a common(though not in C#) coding style

Comment: Just use `//` for the comments and you can ditch the `*/` line.

Comment: Hope the edits are ok. Return type changed to `int` so I could fit a `{` and a space. Most importantly, it now fits the spec

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  I changed the comments and didn't realize I added a line.

Comment: How can we be certain this won't get TCO'd to just loop forever?

Answer (score 25):

```
  123456789012345678
1 ___|_____|_____|__
2 |_____|_____|_____
3 ___|_____|_____|__
4 |_____|_____|_____
5 ___|_____|_____|__
6 |_____|_____|_____
```

It's just another brick in the wall.

Comment: Nice, but you know [some do better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974). ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: tell Jeff to get us `kbd` back, and I'll try.

Comment: You didn't seem to need `kbd` to restore that image after Jeff took `kbd` away!

Comment: +1 for the Pink Floyd reference

Answer (score 24):

```
  123456789012345678
1 StackOverflow.com
2 Dedicated to the
3 tireless effort of
4 expert programmers
5 making this brick
6 [status-complete]
```

Comment: I like this because it's true to the "dedication" nature of the brick, plus contains a bit of the SO purpose and an inside-meme, to boot.

Comment: By all my powers I have just made up, I hereby pronounce you the best brickmaker ever.

Comment: This is nice - punny, on-message, in-jokey, and awesome.

Answer (score 22):

I prefer a more nuanced message:

```
  123456789012345678
1 Add 2 parts Q & A,
2 1 part Wiki,
3 1 part forum.
4 Bake for 6-8 weeks
5 Makes 3-4 servings
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: -1 forgot to mention waffles

Comment: @George: Clearly I'm not spending enough time on meta (for the uninitiated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19392/what-is-up-with-the-waffle-fetish).

Comment: @mike what about s/1 part forum/1 part Waffles  ?

Comment: @Earlz: My other answer has waffles and got no love. I blame John Cusack :(

Comment: WHERE'S THE PONY?

Comment: where do I see 6-8 weeks joke?

Answer (score 22):

```
First brick here?
Check out the FAQ!
```

Comment: sigh.... brick.

Answer (score 21):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow\.com
2.you shouldn't par\
3.se [X]HTML with re
4.gular expressions.
5.have you tried HT\
6.ML Parser instead?
```

Comment: haha, I always hate it when people rain on my cthulu parade!

Answer (score 20):

```
  123456789012345678
1        \   |
2      __  \  |
3        --_ \ |
4    | ______ |
5    |________|
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: [beat you by 25 seconds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46920/a-stack-overflow-brick-in-the-computer-history-museum-wall/46933#46933) :-P

Comment: I think it's unlikely the brick will use a monospace font, though, which means alignment would be problematic

Comment: and the bricks have logos anyway

Comment: Any one have any pictures of actual bricks?

Answer (score 17):

```
if you're looking        
for gender reass-      
ignment, you've          
come to the wrong
place 
 stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: +1 But I'm sure the history books will have long forgotten the hyphen-site, making this one confusing brick :)

Answer (score 17):

```
  123456789012345678
1  
2 
3 (λx.x x) (λx.x x)
4 stackoverflow.com
5 
6
```

Comment: omega, my mega.

Comment: SO - lambda style :)

Answer (score 17):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2
3   eventually
4  we'd like to
5     be an
6    exhibit
```

Answer (score 15):

```
  123456789012345678
1 The only community
2 on the internet
3 where users enjoy
4 when avatars are
5 hacked and turned
6 into unicorns.
```

Comment: Without the hyphen the word `community` just fits fine on that first line, right?

Answer (score 15):

How about:

```
  123456789012345678
1
2            Alconja
3              3,772
4          ●1 ●3 ●16
5  
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Ok, maybe I'm not well known enough... so perhaps:

```
  123456789012345678
1
2          Jon Skeet
3            168,276
4     ●31 ●593 ●1153
5
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Or:

```
  123456789012345678
1
2      Jeff Atwood ♦
3             58,226
4       ●9 ●110 ●190
5
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: I would use some `|`s and `-`s and such to put a "border" around it. Maybe that would look weird.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: Yeah I was going to, except Jeff mentioned that it probably wouldn't be a fixed width font, which would make it come out weird.

Comment: Let Jon buy his own brick!

Answer (score 14):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2  
3 Fixing the
4 internet
5 one question
6 at a time
```

Answer (score 13):

Not to rain in your parade, but this is the kind of neighbours you'd have?

Comment: I'm really hoping these "examples" aren't representative. We're in the high-rent neighborhood..

Comment: @Jeff: that reminds me... who is paying for this? :)

Comment: If someone pays $5k for one of these I'll send them my address so they can send to balance of their excess to me.

Answer (score 13):

The solution is obvious.  You need to buy many bricks, and set them up with graphics of the game breakout.

Answer (score 11):

```
010100110111010001
100001011000110110
101101001111011101
100110010101110010
011001100110110001
10111101110111
```

Comment: I'd prefer it in mixed case or all lower case instead of all caps.

Comment: Just for you, Dennis...

Comment: -1, a lot of bricks will be like that, methinks.

Answer (score 9):

As an extension of Jason's answer:

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 My name is
3 Jeff Atwood.
4 I built this site.
5 It took me six to
6 eight weeks.
```

Comment: And there I thought it would take only a weekend...

Comment: Why not just `And on the eigth week - He rested` , s/-/\n/ because comments won't let me.

Answer (score 9):

This just came to mind:

```
 123456789012345678
1  Our collective
2 attempt at being
3      funny
4   ended up in
5    a museum.
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Meta-meta-meta brick

Answer (score 8):

```
  123456789012345678
0 This brick just
1 holds up a wall.
2 StackOverflow.com
3 holds up the
4 entire community  
5 of developers
```

Comment: Oops. That's 7 lines!

Comment: @Bill Haha, oops.  Didn't even realize it.

Answer (score 7):

```
  123456789012345678
1 My name is
2 Jeff Atwood.
3 I built this site.
4 In case you forgot
5 my name, again, is
6 Jeff Atwood.
```

Comment: That can't be from the real Jeff; you're missing any mention of [status-bydesign].

Comment: That name again is Mr. Plow!

Answer (score 7):

```
      123456789012345678
    1 Honoring
    2 stackoverflow.com
    3 who improved how 
    4 experts exchange 
    5 information. It's
    6 rockhardawesome!
```

Comment: I'm so tempted to stick a hyphen in there...

Comment: @that one guy: Hyphen? I'm tempted to put "experts" in quotes :)

Answer (score 7):

Credit to @Cobbal

```
  123456789012345678
1 
2    plz-send-teh 
3        brickz
4 
5 stackoverflow.com
6
```

Answer (score 7):

```
  123456789012345678
1 StackOverflow.com
2 Our humble attempt
3 to improve the way
4 developers create
5 software for the
6 rest of us.
```

It's a museum, especially one that is highly respected. I think humbleness helps to show respect to the museum and its cause and also to get back some respect in 10, 20 or 50 years.

Answer (score 6):

```
  123456789012345678
1 StackOverflow.com
2 This brick would
3 have been
4 voted up if it had
5 free-hand circles.
6 [status-rejected]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
   123456789012345678
1  If we have made
2  software better,
3  it is by standing
4  on the shoulders
5  of giants.
6  stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 5):

Or if you'd like to throw a philosophical in-joke in...

```
 it took a bit, but
 we learned the 
 important things
 aren't answers,
 but questions.
  stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Except that this is incorrect.

Comment: [subjective-and-argumentative]. Some would argue the important things aren't questions, but Unicorns... :)

Comment: Tell that to the users who lost half of the rep gained from asking questions....

Answer (score 5):

```
  123456789012345678
1     Badges?
2 We don't need no
3    steenkin'
4     badges!
5 
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 123456789012345678
1 I am Jeff Atwood
2   I like computers
3 I am Joel Spolsky
4   I like jam
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 123456789012345678
1 int main(void) {
2     main();
3 } 
4      Dot com
5     Was  here 
6       2010
```

Possibly not language agnostic enough for the whole community, though.

Answer (score 4):

stackoverflow.com

No hyphens needed

Answer (score 4):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2
3   Answered 2009
4
5     Great Brick
6   Community Wiki
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  123456789012345678
0 Stackoverflow.com
1 From the people
2 who write code for
3 these computers:
4 Thank you for 
5 preserving our
6 history and legacy
```

Comment: Too many blocks seem like advertisements for stackoverflow.  I'd like to see the block look like a true gift of appreciation for the work that CHM is undertaking.

Comment: Nice thought, but this could easily be interpreted the opposite way.  That is, developers thanking SO for preserving their old questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
stackoverflow: 
please don't use 
phpBB for question 
and answer sites
```

Comment: s/stackoverflow/stack exchange

Comment: `s/stackoverflow/Stack Overflow/` (or `s/stackoverflow/StackExchange/`)

Answer (score 3):

```
  123456789012345678
1
2 stackoverflow.com
3
4  we have waffles
5
6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 fast
3      free
4           answers
5 run by:
6      the community
```

Comment: `sed s/ran/run/ answer`

Comment: Changed.  Happy?  :-)

Answer (score 3):

An obvious (but not serious) response.

```
  123456789012345678

1 stackoverflow.com
2
3 just another
4  brick in the wall
5
6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
      123456789012345678
    1 StackOverflow.com:
    2 A programming
    3 community exploit.
    4 Founded by Joel
    5 Spolsky and Jeff
    6 Atwood July 2008
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  123456789012345678
0 +1 Why click on
1 stackoverflow.com
2    not working ?
3 
4 +30 Because we are
5   on a brick
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [my other brick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46920/a-stack-overflow-brick-in-the-computer-history-museum-wall/46926#46926) suggestion but with the [Stack Exchange mission](http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0) spiced up to be specific for Stack Overflow.

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 Make the Internet
3 a better place to
4 get expert answers
5 to your program-
6 ming questions
```

Answer (score 2):

```
      ╲ │      
   ╲-  ╲ │ stack         
     ╲- ╲   over        
 │ ---_╲_ │  flow        
 │ ______ │   .com
 └────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  123456789012345678
1 def StackOverflow
2   ask_questions
3   give_answers
4   profit!
5   buy_brick
6 end
```

Valid Ruby code :)

Comment: +1 even though I'm somewhat of a Python lover and Ruby hater.

Answer (score 2):

Text

```
No matter what 
future holds,
We were the first
that worked
stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Computer Science 
  is no more about
   computers than
    astronomy is 
   about telescopes
          -Dijkstra
```

Comment: it's a great quote, but it's more about computer science than it is about programming - i.e. you can't really replace "computer science" in the quote with "programming"

Comment: Agree with Kyle.  Good quote, but not for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
 123456789012345678
1                  
2                  
3  plaque coming   
4  in 6-8 weeks    
5                  
6
```

or

```
 123456789012345678
1                  
2 the plaque will  
3 be ready in      
4 in 6-8 weeks     
5                  
6
```

Comment: `[status-planned]`

Comment: this is more about Jeff Atwood than it is about SO

Answer (score 1):

Boy am I late to the party -- shows me for having a *life* on Friday night! :)

```
  123456789012345678
1 If you grok
2 Ponies and waffles
3 plz-send-teh-codez
4 & status-declined
5 You belong on
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of those (ugly!) [official examples](http://www.computerhistory.org/contribute/impression/images/wall_plaques_big.jpg) certainly don't play by the 18-character rule:

```
123456789012345678            123456789012345678            123456789012345678 
"GOOGLE," a play on           Batman Arkham Asylum          A. Chang has
the word "googol,"            My best gaming                1 Terabyte of digital
the mathematical              addiction - B. Collins        storage..... You?
term for a 1 followed
by 100 zeros.
```

Maybe the rules aren't that strict? $46 per character is quite a lot of money, and I assume the CHM wants things to look nice too...

Answer (score 1):

```
  123456789012345678
1 StackOverflow.com
2 Dedicated towards
3 finding excellent,
4 accurate & lasting
5 answers to every
6 programming issue.

or
6 developer question
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  123456789012345678
1 StackOverflow.com
2 Established 2008
3 to serve everyone
4 who is interested
5 in writing lasting
6 software.
```

Comment: Why "lasting" though?

Comment: Because timeless was too long :) It's my belief that Software we write should be useful for more than 5 minutes - it should still be useful in 5 years, and that is only possible if it's robust and well-architected. It's my belief that the more "hardcore" SO users are interested in writing better architected software rather than just getting the job done as quickly as possible. Also see http://thedailywtf.com/articles/what_could_possibly_be_worse_than_failure_0x3f_.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
  123456789012345678
1 Software is about
2 improving the life
3 of human beings.
4 StackOverflow.com 
5 helps developers
6 to make it happen.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
123456789012345678
0 StackOverflow.com
1 
2   I am the
3    answer 
4    to our
5   question
```

meaning that this brick have an answer to the question, what to write on.

Answer (score 1):

```
  123456789012345678
1 ##################
2 #  >  \    /   \ #
3 #  /           / #
4 #        #       #
5 #  \  /  # \   x #
6 ##################
```

[Lasers!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480023/code-golf-lasers)

Answer (score 1):

```
 123456789012345678
0 Haikus are
1      confusing
2 But the answers
3      do make sense
4 StackOverflow.com
5
```

Comment: "Questions in [and, of] / confusion / But the answers / do make sense"

Answer (score 1):

```
  123456789012345678
0 +1 Why
1 stackneverflow.com
2 not working ?
3 
4 +3 Try to replace
5 'never' with 'over'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try:

```
  123456789012345678
1 To: Skynet
2 You are welcome.
3
4 stackoverflow.com
5
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can use non-alphanumeric characters or not, but how about something really geeky like [Hello world written as a palindrome in Befunge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659752/programming-challenge-can-you-code-a-hello-world-program-as-a-palindrome/730431#730431)

```
  123456789012345678
1 0"dlroW ,olleH"v<
2 @_,^         >#:^
3 ^:#>         ^,_@
4 <v"Hello, World"0
5 
6 stackoverflow.com
```

You would have to check and make sure they use a monospaced font too of course :-P

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of stating what [Stack Overflow is all about](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/backIssues-2009-11.html).

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 We help the
3 world's best
4 developers make
5 better software
6
```

Comment: well, that's what Fog Creek is about, technically

Comment: lol true, but very similar to the stack exchange: Make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions.

Comment: What about us hopeless developers?

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 Couldn't figure
2 out how to put
3 text on this brick
4 thingadongdong.
5
6
```

Comment: Looks like you figured it out...

Answer (score 0):

History, potential for irony if the brick survives the end of the world in 2012 and a mutant zombie survivor visits the museum, *and* waffles!

```
  123456789012345678
1 1804:Jacquard Loom
2 1946:ENIAC 
3 1971:First e-mail
4 2008:stackoverflow
5 2009:Waffles
6 2012:John Cusack?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 
3 Because...
4 Jon Skeet
5 is a prime Number
6
```

Comment: -1 SO is not Jon Skeet

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 
3 Replacing Google
4   question by 
5    question!
6
```

Comment: This is patently wrong, as something like 50% of SO's traffic comes FROM google.

Answer (score 0):

```
 123456789012345678
1 Mortar Overflow
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 
3 For help when 
4 your site has
5 been bricked.
6
```

Comment: Bit web focused.

Comment: @sosh: what do you expect from a web developer? or a brick for a web site? :p

Comment: It is a website, but not solely about websites.

Comment: If anything, this would be the Server Fault brick.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a computer *history* museum, I suggest something about the history of internet Q&A. Stackoverflow's history goes back at least as far as Michael E. Lesk (UUCP) and Tome Truscott & Jim Ellis (Usenet). No doubt some early BBSs as well. And whoever came up with the first web forum.

And a special thanks to the hyphen site for showing us how not to do it. :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 StackOverflow.com
2 is you and every
3 other developer
4 who is dedicated
5 to create software
6 which helps people
```

I know, sounds like a motto for Alt.Net, but I honestly believe that most SO users want to write great software rather than just the bare minimum.

Comment: Many people reading this will not be developers

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 You can't parse   
2 [X]HTML with regex
3 Because HTML can't
4 be parsed by regex
5 find out why...
6 Stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: This is actually a dupe of an earlier answer.  Votes here should prolly be put on the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 How is c pound
2 formed? How is
3 program get
4 compiled?
5 Closed as "not a
6 real question"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 StackOverflow.com
2 The power of
3 crowdsourced
4 programming
5 knowledge
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2       This
3      should
4        be
5    commnunity
6       wiki
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1 "The only thing
2 that will redeem
3      mankind
4 is co-operation."
5 - Bertrand Russell
6 StackOverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   123456789012345678
 1
 2
 3 StackOverflow.com:
 4 Internet++
 5
 6
```

Short and simple, but I think it captures the spirit of making the internet a better place, as well as being a programming reference

Comment: Hello? Awfully sorry to bother you, but I seem to have found a poor semicolon that I believe could be yours. Do you know this `;`?

Comment: @json Yeah, I know, I remembered the semi-colon but I wasn't going for correctness. After all, C++ isn't named "C++;"

Answer (score 0):

```
  123456789012345678
1
2
3     use jQuery
4
5
6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com
2 
3 Where
4 Jon Skeet eats
5 everyone else
6 for breakfeast.
```

Comment: -1 SO is not Jon Skeet

Answer (score -1):

```
  123456789012345678
1 Layout bug with lo
2 stackoverflow.com
3 [bug] [layout]
4 [status-bydesign]
5 Edited by Jeff
6 Atwood ♦
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stacking
2 questions and...
3 answers, since..
4 [created-date]
5 until,
6 [overflow-error]
```

Comment: well well well... no reason and a down vote???

Answer (score -1):

```
  123456789012345678
1 StackOverflow.com
2   Take fifteen 
3  minutes to give
4 an awesome answer
5       ...
6 GODDAMNIT SKEET!!!
```

Comment: similar http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46920/a-stack-overflow-brick-in-the-computer-history-museum-wall/47151#47151

Answer (score -1):

```
123456789012345678
1 StackOverflow.com
2 One small 
3 question, one
3 giant answer
4 for programmers 
5 everywhere.
6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  123456789012345678
0     This is a 
1     registered
2  thingabrickbrick.
3 Stackoverflow.com:
4   Question your
5  thingadongdongs.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  123456789012345678
0 StackOverflow.com
1 where make 
2 questions 
3 and get answer 
4 like
5 this wall -stacked
```

Answer (score -1):

```
123456789012345678
1 google.com
2 how to....??
3 your page
4 automatically
5 redireting to
6 stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  123456789012345678
1 stackoverflow.com 
2 301 Moved
3 Location: http://
4   meta.
5     stackoverflow
6       .com
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  123456789012345678
1    JON SKEET!!!
2  Slowly I turned
3       ...
4   step by step
5       ...
6   inch by inch
```

Comment: similar http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46920/a-stack-overflow-brick-in-the-computer-history-museum-wall/47150#47150

Answer (score -2):

```
   123456789012345678  
 1 Answer  upvote 10+ 
 2 Question upvote 5+ 
 3 Look on your face 
 4 when you find your  
 5 solution PRICELESS
 6 Stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: AFAIK, Comment upvotes give 0 rep.

Comment: Oops .... you are right ... thanx :)

Answer (score -2):

> ```
>   123456789012345678
> 1 Jeff
> 2 and
> 3 Joel
> 4 jumped
> 5 the
> 6 Shark.
> ```

Answer (score -4):

```
  123456789012345678
1 What should I put 
2 on this brick?  
3 Plz-send-teh-codez
```

Comment: It's a bit frightening that `Plz-send-teh-codez` fits perfectly.

Answer (score -7):

Stackoverflow.com

9/10 programmers

agree: It's

teh awesome !!!11

Comment: PLZ HELP BRICK T3XT NO WORK HELPZZZZ!!111!1

Comment: Ya... it's pretty bad.

Comment: [homework][plz-send-teh-brickz]