# Will the community be able to create and choose logo and Theme for StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stackexchange-2.0, logo, design

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Who designs the logos for Area 51 proposals?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/who-designs-the-logos-for-area-51-proposals)
>   [Will all Stack Exchange sites look the same?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same)

In case it's not been planned or proposed already:

It would be nice if in the pre-beta stages the StackExchange Area51 users could submit logo and theme proposals. The community itself could then upvote/downvote for the best logo-theme combination.

Comment: Who is that colour-blind guy behind the bike?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/who-designs-the-logos-for-area-51-proposals for logos, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same for themes - basically, we are encouraged to work on our own logo and design, but if we are unable to come up with something solid or if we need help, Stack Overflow Internet Services Inc. has a team of designers to aid in that work.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer - it's me - but don't worry because I won't be proposing colours for the SE site themes :)

Answer (score 1):

You community should already be doing this. If it isn't, start the process. Your site's meta has all the tools you need to submit contributions, discuss, and vote on ideas.

### [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

> #### #5. What should our logo and site design look like?
>
> This one is pretty straightforward. Solicit contributions, throw out ideas, post preliminary (or finished) designs, and be supportive and respectful of other people’s ideas and creativity.
>
> We have designers on staff to come up with site designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as exceptional, we are happy to use it.