# Who are the artists and designers doing the Stack Exchange sites' excellent artwork?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, images

Each of the current public Stack Exchange sites has a design and look of its own, small refinements, icons, subtle or significant variations on the original theme.

For instance, I like the English and Linux themes very much.

I am really curious about the on-going process of giving a specific visual identity to the new sites currently in beta. Who decides? I have not found information about that in Area 51 (I may not have searched enough).

Can followers and commiters help or contribute on the artwork?

*EDIT* : I realize that my question is a partial duplicate of [a previous question already answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/who-designs-the-logos-for-area-51-proposals).
So let's focus on this feature wish:

I suggest if this is not already the case that there should be a **special design overview page** on each site (or proposal page) that would regroup most of the visual elements needed to "dress" the site, with a comment and discussion system.

Comment: As noted by both answers, this is basically already the case. Our "comment and discussion system" is the site's Meta site, as the design of the site is one of the Top 7 essential features of the site that should be discussed by the community during the beta phase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently the design team is 4 people. As mentioned in other posts, our *Creative Director* **Jin Yang** has been managing the **Stack Exchange** website designs for a very long time. Up until 2013, most of the designs were handled either by Jin or a freelancer hired specifically for that project. Websites which were designed by a freelancer is usually noted in the community's Meta design pitch.

In the last 2 years though, we've started to build out the design team further. Currently the team is:

- [**Jin Yang**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin) — *Creative Director*
- [**Joshua Hynes**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/229714/hynes) — (aka "Me") I work primarily on [**Stack Overflow Careers**](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) though I help out with some community design efforts.
- [**Stéphane Martin**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245505/st%C3%A9phane-martin) — Stéphane works primarily on community designs. He recently helped roll out the new profile designs.
- [**Courtny Cotten**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/248098/courtny-cotten) — Courtny primarily works on the Stack Overflow Careers product.

We have some new team members coming on soon as well, so I'll try to update this list as new people officially come on board.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information!  I knew about Jin and Stéphane from their work on site designs and I knew there were more designers working on Careers, but I hadn't heard any other names before.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if he does all the design work by himself, but Jin Yang is the [Designer in Residence](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) for Stack Exchange.  I have seen him take suggestions and ask for feedback on some of the site-specific Metas before, so the communities do get to have *some* input.

Comment: Well, he does have help on some of them. From memory, the designs for [English Language & Usage](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/400/english-site-design) as well as [AskUbuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/377/design-ideas-for-the-final-site) are not from Jin. I do not know if there are any other sites designed by someone other than Jin.

Comment: He has outsourced some illustrators as well

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Perhaps the post-beta design process could be just a little more explicit in the documentation.

Comment: UX.se (still in beta) is [also outsourced](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/q/293/2279 "New Design Launched"). The design is done by Dmitry from Usabilitypost and the design process is described in [his blog post](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2011/04/22/designing-ux-exchange/ "Designing UX Exchange").

Answer (score 2):

I believe Jin does the design work.

When a site goes into beta, there may be a topic on the meta site (like [Gaming's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshots-v2) or [Apple's](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268/design-for-the-apple-stackexchange-site)) where you can submit feedback and ideas. Prior to the actual beta, design isn't the important part of Area 51 so I don't think anyone really cares the artwork or style at that point.