# Who designs the Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who are the artists and designers doing Stack Exchange sites' excellent artwork?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87220/who-are-the-artists-and-designers-doing-stackexchange-sites-excellent-artwork)

Who designs the Stack Exchange websites? I am just curious as to whom we may give a pat on the back for a job well done :)

They surely are consistent, and all around easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know who designed the original trilogy (Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User), but [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) does most of the SE 2.0 sites.

He has contracted out the designs to a few (Ask Ubuntu being one), check out the per site meta for Jin's posting on the site's design for more information on each one.

Comment: stackoverflow.com was designed by Jeremy Kratz http://stackoverflow.com/users/4258/jeremy-kratz originally. Jeff and the core dev team have been tweaking it since. SF/SU were based off on the same design.