# No more waffles?

Tags: discussion, waffles

[waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles). Ordinary member? He's no longer in the Stack Exchange team page nor in the moderators list of any site.

He was part of the team [from almost the beginning](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00008/), doesn't he deserve a big farewell party like Jeff had?

Looks like he [stepped down willingly](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/06/14/leaving-stack-exchange) couple of weeks ago - so goodbye, and thanks for all the waffles!

[image: no more waffles]

Comment: This is why my meta alter ego wants more waffles :)

Comment: @Man you ATE WAFFLESSS???!!

Comment: @sha - You should come to the tavern more if you want to [stay up-to-date](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/995370#995370) :P

Comment: @Lix I know myself - for me chat is a honey trap, I will stay there forever and lose my wife, job and kids! (not in the same order, but still) :D

Comment: @shadow no, I want him back. The waffle level of MSO is  declining at an alarming rate, it needs more waffles. Hence "ManishEarth wants more waffles" :) Though I did have some for breakfast yesterday :P

Comment: Those look like pancakes to me...

Comment: @razlebe sharp eyes! Well, I don't want him to get fat you know :D

Answer (score 29, accepted):

He left.

http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/06/14/leaving-stack-exchange

Comment: Noooooooooooooo

Comment: Tears in heaaaven, do do dooo do dooooo :(

Answer (score 53):

### Thank you!

[image: my delicious parting gift]

It is very rare to have job you where every day is [the weekend](http://xkcd.com/1073/). I feel extremely lucky to have had the team mates I had and the pleasure of working with the **AWESOME** community that makes Stack Exchange so amazing.

Thank you all for making this job, "not a job". Thank you for letting me take an active part in this mammoth effort.

---

Now, it is time for me to pick my next adventure!

[image: waffles]

Comment: HA! About time you posted something about it on MSO...

Comment: your MSO profile says it's an  answer number 1000 here; you've got just a few more to go (24) to nicely looking 0x400

Comment: You are very welcome! Honoured to be the one to pick up the glove - even though by chance after noticing your diamond was gone. ;)

Comment: Nice heels, waffles :)

Comment: **Aussie Aussi Aussie, oi oi oi**. Best of luck waffles, thanks for the awesome work on SE.

Answer (score 36):

Waffles will always be a button push away...

[image]