# Question View in Bounty tab is missing the diamonds

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Precious diamonds are lost when viewing questions in the Bounty tab: (active, offered and earned)

> [image]

At first I was horrified, thinking "Maybe they both RETIRED???" but then I was at ease when understanding their diamond is safe and it's just a local problem with this specific view.

[Link for reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard?tab=bounties&sort=offered). (aka for the lazy folk :))

Comment: No, no. We both retired.

Comment: This is actually on all profile tabs that display questions this way. For some reason I thought it was intentional, but maybe not.

Comment: @Oded I'm already [traumatized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138012/152859)! ;)

Comment: @Tim well, it [wasn't really intentional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175558/152859). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, some common code here wasn't putting the user type in the query, so the render didn't know about the mod status.

This will be fixed in the next build, most likely tomorrow.