# Please welcome your new Stack Overflow moderator - animuson!

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, election, moderators

A [seasoned veteran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson), [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson) will be stepping up to help fill the *huge* vacancy left by Will, who departed from the team [for personal reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187557/50049) earlier this week. Next in line from the [last election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4), animuson takes his post in service of this community today.

Please give him a warm welcome and congratulations as he jumps feet first (or head first, if he has a helmet - we only provide hats) into his new role!

Comment: Does he only take over the regular moderator duties, or also the meme-posting in TL?

Comment: Primarily the meme-posting for now; mod-duties will come later.

Comment: Ah good. Will left a sizable hole in the roster. Welcome aboard animuson!

Comment: Woot! I knew there was a way to get all the peeps I wanted in from the last election! Congrats to animuson!

Comment: ["Oh, and sunglasses confuse me."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson) - Heh, [I'm going to have fun with this one](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a610732cb6ac525c26ff5bcfa9433f41?s=256)...

Comment: "Holy massive @Yannis Batman!".

Comment: @Yannis: In case anyone is wondering, that is a reference to my [previous Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/userimage/6424765/d2ccd0e188b223bb28e4c635a1e51bf4.jpg?size=256).

Comment: @animuson Oh, good you're here. Now get in TL, we have to start your training asap. It'll be a tough first week, but once we beat the user out of you, you'll be fine.

Comment: If he's seasoned, can we eat him?

Comment: animuson is my first choice in the election

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't I be next in line for mod instead of animuson, according to the [election](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5SZPq.png)?

Comment: @Raghav: this comes up every time we do a call-up; you can't reliably guess the results of a 5-person election (much less a 6-person election) from those of a 4-person election - you're lowering the bar for being elected, so some folks might not get eliminated and go on to pick up sufficient votes. Here's what the last SO election looks like with 6 picks: http://www.opavote.org/results/1974007/0

Comment: @Shog9 Ah that clears it up. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 20):

That's just great! I was hoping to see a moderator elected with **that** participation on Meta and knowledge of this network.