# question locked as I was writing comprehensive answer

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, locked-questions

So, after spending twenty minutes building an answer to [Catch-22 prevents streamed TCP WCF service securable by WIF; ruining my Christmas, mental health](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691482/catch-22-prevents-streamed-tcp-wcf-service-securable-by-wif-ruining-my-christma) , a moderator locked it literally five seconds before I could post the answer. What's the process to appealing the locked status? It was locked due to confusion over the question, but I understand it perfectly having been through the same problem.

Comment: Locks are (usually) temporary and will (usually) be removed relatively quickly

Comment: ok, I will check periodically. I presume there is no way to register for notifications of it being unlocked (not owning the question myself.)

Comment: I don't believe so. For what its worth; I don't believe it was locked because it was unclear (in such cases its usually put on hold) but because of the ensuing rollback war between the humerous and non humerous versions

Comment: You can flag for moderator attention and make your case. They can respond to you in your flags list

Comment: It seems to be unlocked now (a free unlock notification ;)).

Comment: @Pëkka Thanks - I did not notice that functionality. I wonder if it works when a question is locked though :)

Comment: A "close" vote because it is not about stackoverflow? Well, yes it is, it's about the question locking process. No?

Comment: The reason is "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question."

Comment: The question in this case was locked because of a "content dispute"; to wit, the comical hyperbole (discussed at [Editing out the dramatics from a question that may have been upvoted because of style](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214957)). Questions don't get locked because they're unclear or cause confusion; they get _closed_ in that case.

Comment: Close voters...  that is ridiculous. Of course this can happen again and users should be able to refer to this question in that case. That close reason is more for "this obscure bug only happened to me but it went away."

Comment: To close voters: while this did occur on Stack Overflow, the question also applies to other sites in the network. I do not think it should be closed as "pertains to only one site in the network".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This particular situation was resolved soon after it started, but for future reference:

First, just **be a little bit patient**: locks are usually temporary, and when the problem that resulted in locking has been resolved the lock will be removed.

Second, **help resolve the problem** (if you can) - at very least, don't add to it. Start a meta discussion, invite others involved in the dispute in and throw out some constructive solutions to the dispute. **Do not** use this as an opportunity to continue throwing gasoline on whatever fire the lock was intended to smother!

Finally, if you think the situation has been resolved and the lock isn't scheduled to be removed any time soon, **flag and ask a moderator to lift it.** Include a link to the meta discussion if there is one, or at least a short description of why you feel the lock is no longer needed.

Comment: which is exactly what I did! How meta! meta-meta?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I _think_ non-moderators cannot see the countdown.

Comment: You're correct, @Michael.