# Comments are now diamond killers

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderators

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit any post where a diamond mod/dev/employee left a comment.
2. Add your own comment.
3. Bask in the temporary glory of vaporizing his/her diamond:

   > [image]
4. Reloading brings such diamond back.

(no real diamonds were harmed during this bug report)

**Also, all diamonds are lost when clicking "add / show [x] more comments" when post has too many of them.** ([test case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216166/152859))

Also worth to mention it affects both full site and mobile site themes, so it's not just a CSS issue.

Comment: This is temporary until a page refresh?

Comment: I don't think you need to comment after the mod to make this happen.  I don't see random's diamond [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216166/experimented-with-an-alternate-account-to-see-the-new-user-experience-through-ve#comment699581_216166) and my comment is before his.

Comment: @Duncan not what I've seen.... I still don't see random's diamond in the comment I mentioned above.

Comment: @psubsee2003 oh my, maybe it's a bigger bug than I thought!

Comment: @Duncan that particular diamond of the dev was restored after reload,  but psubsee is also correct, let me check

Comment: I have also seen this without commenting myself at all (before or after): resolved on refresh though. Sadly ruining my rebellion plans

Comment: @psubsee2003 OK, found the reason. Editing the report...

Comment: @ShadowWizard: random's diamond does not show up for me at all. Maybe it has also something to do with "load more comments"? Seems like most (all?) JavaScript requests are effected.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby because when browsing to specific comment, the comments are auto expanded, so it's the same as clicking the "add/show more comment" hence diamonds are lost.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby [this example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215694/182513) is a better demonstration.  Robert's diamond is there on his comments, but when you expand the comment chain, they all diappear.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Ahhh...I managed to interpret "add / show [x] more comments" as "add new comment" then the button that is exactly labeled like that...

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby now that's a special skill! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yeah, I'm very special...people keep telling me all the time. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We'll tolerate no more of your diamond killing shenanigans! ...after the next build.

*Edit:* In response to the comment on this answer: no comment.

Comment: I see you didn't comment at all.  Are you afraid someone was going to kill your diamond before the fix is deployed?

Comment: LOL The edit...

Comment: Still not fixed! (yeah, trying to lure Nick to post comment ;-))

Comment: Close, but no cigar! The diamond persists, but the mod/dev/employee name goes a little to the left making it look weird.