# What about a Master badge

Tags: feature-request, review, badge-request

This Badge should be awarded after 10.000 review tasks.

After gained the Steward badge for closing votes, and soon for other review types, I was wondering if we could aim higher. A gold badge, "Master", for reviewing 10.000 would be very desirable.

---

Still being downvoted. But what the heck. **The hump of close votes has only increased by 5.000 since I last wrote**. Now 6.7k. Regardless of the effort trying to reduce it. I am convinced that one day stackoverflow introduces a new badge. As I told them to. Just a matter of time.

I guess it will go as the conflict between Darwin and his opponents :

**First step**:
This is the most extreme idea I have ever heard!!

**Second step:**
It may be true, but is not interesting and have no scientific value

**third step**:
I have always said the same, all the time

A badge, for monitoring more than 1000 posts, maybe 4000, is just on the loop.

Comment: Please Nooooo - we're being flooded with terrible review tasks as it is, just because of people aiming for that one badge. Imagine what would happen if there'd be an incentive for those uers to go on beyond the required 250 items for that. Related: [The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561) and [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137784)

Comment: OK, well, there is 113.4k close votes to be processed ... Still increasing.

Comment: that... or it's a really bad idea.

Comment: I have 229 point to go = you have 114 downvotes left. Go for it!

Comment: It's too bad you are taking the negative feedback on your suggestion personally. Don't. Some people just think it's an idea that (however well meant) would have some very negative side effects. There's now even a moderator who stepped up to provide an extensive report on robo-reviewers below. Not sure what else we can do

Comment: I agree with you, but what are my options? I cannot delete my question, since there is an answer. And the only thing I has done bad was suggest a new feature. Gee! I look at the bright side. This could be downvoted so much that I dont have any reputation left. That could be fun. What else can I do?

Comment: don't worry too much about the reputation. My first post on Meta ever received -9, as I recall. Every upvote on a question will gain you +5 and on answers +10, so any loss will be alleviated over time through other contributions. New feature suggestions are always welcomed, and there is nothing fundamentally wrong with this one, but it hit a very recent nerve with problems of misuse and unintended consequences of badges. It happens occasionally, don't worry too much.

Comment: Jeff Atwood, the founder of the site, has [over 150 downvoted questions and answers,](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=146) the most downvoted one at -192 :)

Comment: Hmmm - okay :-) But I still feel it could be a good idea. Encouraging people to review especially close votes. But you are right, apperently I am wrong.

Comment: it would be a fine idea, if not for the few who don't care for quality at all. :(

Comment: Make one for 10000 close votes review instead. These logs need to clear somehow

Comment: @davidkonrad I rolled back your edit. Do not edit a question into a completely new one after it has been answered.

Comment: @Louis, just fine - thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I disagree with this. We are already offering three badges for each review task. I don't see any point for offering more badges for the same task. If we offer more badges, surely [robo-reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561) will come back and start robo-reviewing *again* after they have earned [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) badge.

Comment: It could (perhaps) reduce the hump of more than 100k close votes to questions.

Comment: I dont believe robo-viewers is the question here or is a problem for SO, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @davidkonrad - I would prefer the queue to increase rather than it is reviewed by robo reviewers. The queues are there to increase the quality of questions, not to decrease the quantity of the queue itself.

Comment: Have you any proof of the queue has ever been "reviewed by robo reviewers"? Sounds rather paranoid to me.

Comment: @davidkonrad - Proof? We have [a tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-abuse) for it. You can [search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=robo+reviewer) by yourself.

Comment: A tag is not a proof. Have the SO-team ever encountered successfully robo reviews?

Comment: @davidkonrad, hims056 is talking about queue reviewers who don't pay attention to the post being reviewed, and just blindly click a button. Not literal bots. And yes, they're incredibly prevalent. Follow the links.

Comment: Please check some top questions related to it. SE team knows this very well that's why they have started [review audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-audits).

Comment: But they are quarantined -right? The SO logic spot them out. Can only see one serious Q in the links, and that looks like some kind of joke.

Comment: Follow the links, @david, and look for comments from users with a diamond after their name, if you're looking for a more official SE POV.

Comment: I follow and read the links. They prove my opninion more than they prove the opposit. And to make it clear, if you halt on logic : If robo reviewers is a problem, why, then, give award badges for people (or robos) after 1000 tasks, but not 10.000 tasks? It is the same deal.

Comment: The posts with data are there, and I don't know what to say to you when you say they're not.  I do wish the extrinsic motivations for reviewing were modified, yes.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, Yes, I know - but so far has there not been any "diamond" present. Hope it changes .. I stand by my idea.

Comment: Oh, for Pete's sake, @david. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158418/careless-review-upvotes-are-actively-contributing-to-the-quality-problem-not-co

Comment: @Michael, SO is not open for robo reviewers. If it was, SO didnt exists. There is the audits and so on. The links does not prove there exists successfully robos, they mention the possibility.

Comment: "By the time I was done, someone else had reviewed the same post simply by upvoting it, so I only got a "Next" button, not an "I'm done" button. My edit still counted as an edit; but no longer as a review." give me a break

Comment: The data you asked for has been provided. Now you're being difficult. Good night.

Comment: Is that proof of a robo?

Comment: @davidkonrad - what type of proof you want here? A comment from SE team like "*Yes we accept that the robo-reviewers exist in SO*"? When SE team implements [features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158505/187824) to prevent careless reviewers, do you want further proof?

Comment: Yes. I want further proof. I dont believe it. I believe SO's algorithms is too smart than you can trick them out by a simple, llame script. But I will try. It is weekend, I will try to create an account with reputation enough to start reviewing. If I achive that, I will make a script trying to review over and over, as you claim "robos" does. If I can do that, you are all right.

Comment: @davidkonrad - But before starting a new account take [a permission](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216174/187824) from the SE team.

Comment: oops, seems like a good idea - Thank you very much.

Comment: But hey, the imaginary robos do not ask.

Comment: @hims056, the comments to that experiment is insane

Comment: @david maybe there is a misunderstanding here. The term "robo-reviewers" doesn't generally refer to a *script* when used on Meta; it refers to reviewers who don't care about the quality of their reviews, they just want the badge. I see dozens and dozens of those every day, approving garbage edits and sometimes even spam. I see dozens and dozens of such bad reviews every day; they're immensely frustrating. If you seriously claim that problem doesn't exist, I don't think we can have a serious discussion here

Comment: Oh, sorry for the broken copy&paste

Comment: @davidkonrad - OK, you want an "official" response, I'm a moderator on SO. As of right now, there are 120 people banned from review on the site, almost all for repeatedly failing system-imposed audits. These aren't automated scripts, they are people sitting behind a computer clicking one button over and over to try to get some imaginary badge. When you click one action 100% of the time, with an average review time of 3 seconds, there's no way you are reading anything that appears in front of you. Worse, there are people who have found ways to game audits, and we deal with them personally.

Comment: Things were far worse in the brief period between when review badges were introduced and we added the audits. We're still cleaning up all the spam that was approved (and even upvoted) during that period. Hundreds and hundreds of people have attempted to game reviews to get these badges, and it has caused active harm to the site. Ask any SO moderator and they will tell you the same story. Aside from the timing, it's very clear that this was all badge-related when you'd see reviewers game reviews up to the point where they got a gold badge, stop immediately, and then start gaming another queue.

Comment: @BradLarson, thank you for the answer. This leaves two questions / observations : 1. It is **not true** that a "master"-badge could attract more "robos". 2. "Robos" is actually **not** a problem for SO. Right?

Comment: @david I'm not sure how one could have read Brad's comments and reach that conclusion? They are a *huge* problem.

Comment: @pekka, the SO employee seems to disagree.

Comment: @pekka, what part of "_there are 120 people banned from review on the site, almost all for repeatedly failing system-imposed audits. These aren't automated script_" didnt you understand?

Comment: @david you seem to be the one who doesn't understand here. As said repeatedly now, *those problem users, and those that haven't been banned yet, are what we are referring to as "robo-reviewers" here.* They are an ongoing problem, and not all of them are being caught.   There is no problem with automated scripts, just with human reviewers trying to game badges. The mechanisms built to catch them are imperfect, as there is no way to check the validity of a "good/bad" vote. We have [a similar new epidemic going on right now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214565) with mundane tag edits.

Comment: I just have to end this :-)

Comment: And what it is the "mundane"-tag edits. You may excuse me, I am not totally into this sort of specialized english.

Comment: "There is no problem with automated scripts", as I suspected.

Comment: I think I understand now. Your real problem is too many people trying to get badges. And you have a hard time follow people, and a new bagde as I suggested would just make it even harder?

Comment: I understand that. You are not google or apple or MS. You are not having unlimited resouces. I just thought you have cracked the problem by determerniting if it is man or algorithm. I still think you have, SO is great, but I understand now why 10.000 reviews as a badge is a bad idea.