# Meta SE 404 page image is dull

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, error-message

I see the [waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19392/what-is-up-with-the-waffle-fetish) 404 page didn't survive the migration. The current image is the default for beta sites. Is there a better image in the works to replace the somewhat bland '[404](https://meta.stackexchange.com/404)' and '[oops](https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?error=error&error)'?

Comment: Waffles is still on mSO. :(

Comment: +1, **bring back the waffles!**

Answer (score 22):

Please, oh please, FOR THE LOVE OF META! Use this as a 404:

[image: epic gif]

Comment: "Firefox has crashed"

Comment: http://pyrrha.csisdmz.ul.ie/4012/animated-gifs/IWQNcGes9u.gif and +1 as required by tavern law. I kind of want to downvote my own answer now.

Comment: But this is a GIF of a fox finding exactly what it was hunting for. Not really suited to a 404.

Comment: @sevensideddie "We couldn't find the page you were looking for. At least the red fox found his mouse. (Link)"

Comment: @Mooseman I stand corrected! That is a winning caption.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Or "Next time, face North."

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Comment: Better for deleted questions.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the MSE 404 page remains bland, and while I do miss the waffles, I propose the following in their place:

[image]

There is also a [slightly larger version](http://rsvpster.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/panic-beaker.gif). I am unable to determine the origin of this particular GIF for attribution.

I believe Beaker is worthy of carrying the waffle torch.

Comment: -1 Not enough jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the [Russian Stack Overflow "oops page"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/error?error=error&error) is doing:

[image: pic]

A kitty would be nice.

Comment: This is more fitting for general error page, not 404 error page.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes. The question says: "Is there a better image in the works to replace the somewhat bland '404' and ***'oops'***?"

Comment: I'm a kitty! I'm nice!