# Awarded bounty shows as active bounty in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, android-app

When I view [What is up with the waffle fetish?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19392/what-is-up-with-the-waffle-fetish) in the Android app, it tells me that there is an active bounty with +100. When I click for more information on the active bounty, the app force closes because there is no active bounty on the question. Upon further inspection, Jeff's answer has been awarded the +100 bounty.

I haven't been able to reproduce on other questions outside of Meta. Unsure if that is related though.

<sup>using v1.0.31</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! This is fixed in the next version of the app, 1.0.32. It turned out this was an issue with the API, the question was returning a `bounty_amount` and a `bounty_closes_date` which is what I do my "if these aren't null, show the banner" check against. This will get fixed on the API eventually, but for now the app does a "and the close date is in the future" check too, fixing this issue.

Comment: Sounds great! I'm still running 1.0.31, and the message no longer appears. Guessing someone updated the API?

Comment: @StevenV Yeah, Kevin beat me to the punch.