# Thank you, Marc Gravell!

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team, thanks

Today, valued associate #6 [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) announced [he's leaving the company](https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/1450009591090143236):

> Excited, scared, happysad.
>
> The end of a personal era; after over 11 years (https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/09/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007/), this is my last week at Stack Overflow (entirely personal reasons; the company is fine, would recommend as a decent employer). Have new role lined up, will discuss in due course.

Thank you Marc, for the work you've done to make this a great place, including [all the bugs you fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:23354+%5Bstatus-completed%5D) and for your valuable contributions to various [open](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) [source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) [libraries](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net) used all over the world (including at my company).

Comment: _*takes hat off to Marc*_... a question:  Is your stance pro-pancake, anti-waffle?  (And please don't hit me with the rolled-up newspaper).  P.S: Waffles.

Comment: @Ollie https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19392/what-is-up-with-the-waffle-fetish#comment39346_19397

Comment: @Ollie I think we all need to think beyond traditional limits of our imagination, and dare to dream. Dream of a world where pancakes and waffles can live side by side, or even stacked. And more importantly: join forces to fight against our common enemy: ***flan***

Comment: Before you get too excited about the bugs I've fixed: take a moment to consider that I also caused quite a few of those, and a great many more that y'all didn't notice. Perhaps because we were suddenly, and perhaps not coincidentally: offline

Comment: So @MarcGravell who is going to fix the TagEngine™ now when it behaves unexpectedly?

Comment: @rene No one worthy, that's for sure... But we'll give it our best to keep it in rein!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Aw, shucks. You're all very welcome. I've had a great time with Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange as a community, and as a company. I really appreciate the kind words - I wasn't ignoring you: I literally wasn't aware of this post until a few minutes ago. 11+ years is a long time by tech retainment standards. I still intend hanging around in Stack Overflow for tech questions. I might even petition for that diamond back at some point (I am also technically an elected moderator, although it predates us having systems to perform or track elections, and I don't think we ever bothered backfilling the missing data). I'm very much looking forward to seeing what other new things Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange bring into the products over the coming years.

Comment: Your 1000th answer on MSE is saying goodbye! Thanks for the 1000 answers on MSE!