# Are we celebrating Marc Gravell's farewell on /users?tab=moderators page of every site? :)

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, moderators, stack-exchange-team

While checking the list of moderators on a main site, I'm surprised to find the name of a staff member! Yes, **[Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) is appearing on all sites.**

Here is a screenshot of [`/users?tab=moderators` page of the site](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) where I have a mod appointment:

> [image]

You can take a look at that page `https://<anysite>.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators` on any site to check.

I have also tried https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators out of curiosity:

> [image]

Thinking that this might be a feature-update, I have checked MSE and found that [Thank you, Marc Gravell!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370959/260388) is leaving the company.

So, I assume this to be some bug or...<reading title of this question> :)

<sub>Note: Community moderators can also find him on /admin dash board with the comment "Moderator has not accepted the agreement".</sub>

Comment: He's not staff anymore, he quit his job in Stack Exchange.

Comment: This kinda happens with many 'oldtimer' staff and is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just de-moded Marc's account across the network. Might take a few minutes for all the diamonds to disappear (and I'll do Area 51 manually tomorrow).

> Goodbye Marc Gravell :-(
> We appreciate your work
> very very much

Comment: Psst. I still have way too much access on chat, but that can be a problem for next week :) (there's a checklist with scripts; I left a link on my way out the door on Friday) It has been a pleasure, Yaakov.

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't get the memo with the link, but I think that I took care of chat. If you see anywhere else, let me know. I'll delete these commetns in a day or so.