# Can folks that edit tags make sure they preserve the information that they would be editing away?

Tags: discussion, tags, etiquette

I have noticed that some folks edit the tags associated with questions to make the tag more generic, like converting [netbeans6.8](/questions/tagged/netbeans6.8) to [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans).

I think this is a good thing.

BUT, most users/askers do not include version information in the text of their question and some of them do pick the 'versioned' tag.  That additional information is valuable at that point.

Please read the question before you edit version info out of tags.  If the version information is not in the question's text then take another moment to edit the text of the question, so the information is immediately available to folks that are trying to answer questions.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41206/should-questions-be-tagged-with-both-a-tag-and-a-sub-tag

Answer (score 2):

It's good to be aware of, but there's always the possibility that the user (especially a new user) hasn't gotten the right tags in the first place.  The tag auto-completion sometimes lists a versioned tag before a generic tag, and it's easy to accidentally grab a tag you didn't really intend.

So if the question doesn't specifically mention a version, but a tag does, adding a note to the post during the edit is a fairly good policy.  In those cases where it's especially unclear, leave a comment asking the poster for feedback (to verify the version, or indicate that the version isn't actually important to the question).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that while a new user may unintentionally pick the wrong tag, swapping the specific for the generic may **sometimes** remove information the user actually **intended** to include.

As an alternative, what I do in this situations is to add the generic tag, but leave the specific tag alone, and add a comment asking the OP if they really wanted the specific tag