# Marking Micro edits

Tags: feature-request, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers)

It would be nice to have some kind of checkbox when editing, that says `micro edit (no content changes)`.

**Why?** 
Sometimes posts do not change in their information but minor errors (typos, formatting mistakes, ...) are corrected. In most of these cases it does not make sense to "push" the post up to the top page or "count it down" towards the community wiki.

One could also say, that a series of successive small edits (less than 10 chars) will not be counted each on its own, but merged to one "big" edit.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I like how the first five words of this question are the same as the first five words of the duplicate: "It would be nice to"

Comment: Also related: [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review)

Comment: Why is it that I always search for the wrong words, when I want to avoid duplicates?