# Review queue to approve edits to very old posts with/without bumping

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, bump

Following up on the discussion [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/should-we-block-edits-of-very-old-questions/3016?noredirect=1#comment6812_3016), I make the following proposal to address the problem of edits to *lots* of very old posts causing newer posts to be bumped down.

- Create a new review queue for edits of very old posts.
- Users with sufficient reputation for the review privilege would choose one of following three options:

  - Reject the edit for one of the usual reasons (too minor, attempt to answer, question as comment, etc.)
  - Accept the edit, but do not bump the post. (If the edit improves *something*, but is not worthy enough of everyone's attention.)
  - Accept the edit, and bump the post (If edit is significant enough that everyone needs to look at it.)
- As it happens with other review queues, bump the post only if 5 reviewers agree.
- Alternatively, one could add a check-box to the Suggested Edits review, to enable the reviewer to allow or disallow bumping.

Comment: This was migrated to MSE at the request of the OP.

Comment: This feature request seems related: [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a new queue is necessary here, as the system *is* well aware of a post being quite old. It's entirely conceivable that we could show older posts in a more visually-distinct manner, and offer users the ability to 'approve quietly'.

On the one hand, I am *generally* against not bumping things because not bumping means giving up free eyeballs to look at whatever just changed - something we've come to find is *invaluable* in a culture of editors and curators.

On the other hand, the whole *purpose* of said queue is oversight so that we get eyeballs on things that folks without privileges say need changing.

I have to think about it. I don't think it's a horrible idea, but I don't want to add an entire queue unnecessarily. We've got another queue coming up soon as part of the quality project, which I *hoped* would cap us at the number of total queues available.

Comment: The last bullet in my post could be relevant if you don't want to add a new queue. When a user reviews a Suggested Edit, point out to them that this edit is over N days old, and give them the option to decide if the edit is significant enough to be bumped up. It isn't much useful to bump posts which only correct minor spelling mistakes, but at the same time, one cannot reject such edit suggestions. This becomes a problem when multiple minor edits are suggested (typically, by new users to get some early reputation push).