# Possibility to restrict search results by date of the most recent answer (or any answer)?

Tags: feature-request, answers, search, filtering, dates

According to [search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) there are two possibilities how search results can be restricted to some date range. Namely `created:` and `lastactive:`. The latter is based on the last activity of the post, for example if I search for use today's date, like [is:q lastactive:2016-06-03](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+lastactive%3A2016-06-03), I will get questions which were active today. After sorting by activity, I get something very similar to the [active questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active). Of course, I can combine this search query with other criteria, for example, I can restrict the search to my favorite tags.

If I understand the way *last activity* works correctly, the above returns questions with any type of activity. Including, for example, a minor edit of an answer to fix a typo or grammar. Many users would like to see only posts where some significant changes were made. (I think that several discussions about bumping on per-site-metas and [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review) confirm that there might be interest in something like that.) Adding new answer is not perfect for this, but it is still a good approximation of significant change.

> Would it be possible to add also `answered:` search operator? (Or some other, more suitable name, if this can be confused with `isanswered:`. Maybe `answerdate:` or `answerposted:`?)
>
> It would return questions where an answer was created in the given date range. (In particular, this could be used to search for questions where new answer was added recently.)

Of course, if there already is a way to search like this and I am simply unaware of it, I would be glad to learn about such search queries.

I am aware that there is [list of new answers to old questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) in [moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/10k-tools/info). But moderator tools are only available to 10k+ users. And this list is different from what I am asking for in this post.

I should also point out that I consider [is:a created:2016-06-03](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+created%3A2016-06-03) to be different from what this feature request is asking for. This query displays answers rather than questions.