# Option to limit main page username associations to post authors

Tags: discussion, edits, display-names, homepage

Question and answer posts are the meat of SE sites.  A significant portion of posts could potentially benefit from editing, but editing is a background curation function that, by definition, is not supposed to substantively change the post.

On the site's main page, there are two primary views.  **Newest** questions always identifies the author of the question, regardless of answers or post modifications.  **Active** questions and **Home** list the username of whoever most recently did anything to any post in the thread.  That has the benefit of identifying the author of answer posts as long as nobody has more recently edited anything in the thread.

Displaying the author of the most recent post on the thread has value.  People can spot a new user and check out their post.  People often have "favorite" authors whose posts they like to read.  The post author gets their name on the main page for a little recognition.  People sometimes remember who the author was rather than the precise title of the question and use that to help locate a recent thread on the main page.

Nobody cares who fixed a typo in a thread or improved the question's tags.  In fact, the only case I can think of where an editor's name could be important is a post with critical issues that's attracting closure votes or downvotes.  Seeing on the main page that a trusted editor modified the post might encourage people to revisit the post and revise their voting.  Yet even minimal post polishing gets the author's name replaced with the editor's name on the main page, a loss of valuable information.

This introduces an additional issue on tiny sites.  I'll use Arts & Crafts as an example because it happens there with some frequency.

The site gets only a trickle of new questions, sometimes going several days without a new one, so main page turnover is extremely slow.  At 50 posts/page, the main page Active view covers about 6 weeks (compared to just hours or days on some of the big sites).

A substantial portion of the site's posts can benefit from editing.  Aside from addressing critical issues, many of the posts are from new users who aren't proficient at posting or for whom English is a second language.  Even for many of the experienced users, things like typos and grammar aren't a high priority.

A handful of users do the vast majority of content curation, with two of us often accounting for most of the edits.  As a result, our two names often dominate the main page.

Besides depriving visitors of the important author information, and depriving the authors of their time in the sun, it hurts the sense of community.  It gives the appearance that it's our personal site, or at least that there is limited variety on the site.  It might even discourage other users from engaging in content curation because there's the appearance that we've got it covered.  My own opinion is that it probably negatively impacts user retention.

The policy puts us in the counterproductive position of needing to weigh the quality of the site's knowledge base against overwhelming the main page with our names, and skipping edits.

I would like to suggest a new view/filter or option so that the main page show only the authors' names (questions and answers), never editor names.  The editors can continue to be shown as an additional entry on the actual thread.  The main page can also continue to show the post "status" (asked, answered, modified) as information independent of the listed author.

@Makyen makes an excellent point in the comments (and other comments confirm), that the needs are different on different sites and for different users, so implementation of the solution shouldn't be deletion of an existing feature.  Rather, this should be an additional available view or option.

Comment: On the other hand, seeing the editor name in the active question list can make it easier to decide which posts are worth revisiting. For example here on meta are a couple of users who are notorious for making maaaaany tag only edits to verrrrrry old posts. If I see their name pop up in the active question list, I can safely assume that nothing interesting was added and there is no need to open the post.

Comment: *Nobody cares who fixed a typo in a thread or improved the question's tags.* If a user suddenly started bumping or mass-editing posts, it's easier to catch.

Comment: From the comments, it sounds like big sites have some potential issues that aren't a problem at tiny sites, and the tiny site  issue of a few editors dominating the main page for a long time is greatly watered down on large sites and quickly disappears.  The priorities and incentives are different.  Maybe there isn't a one-size-fits-all solution.  It also might fall to the site mods to reign in someone doing out-of-control minor edits. Super User went thru a number of big tag cleanups, and we needed to remind editors to not overwhelm the main page.

Comment: Even small sites have an issue e.g. eBooks It has very few new posts, on some days most of the front page consists of questions bumped by the Community Bot - This needs to be shown so as not to waste time reading old stuff which you have already seen.

Comment: @mmmmmm, yeah, Community Bot bumping requires its own solution.  Not sure what that is. Maybe as simple as adding an icon to identify it, which wouldn't seriously change the space requirements?

Comment: This, like many feature requests, assumes that the way that would work best for the OP is the way that it would be best for everyone and that the current way things work isn't useful to anyone (i.e. removes it). Personally, I find the current operation useful on the two sites which I generally monitor: MSO and MSE, so I'm against this change, because it's requesting the removal of features which I use. If it was proposing to *add* an additional way of viewing the the Home Active list, then I could see myself supporting it, even if the current way (what I find useful) was no longer the default.

Answer (score 6):

I think by removing the editor information, you are more treating a symptom than the actual cause.

The active question list is a jack of all trades. It serves (at least) two congruent purposes at once:

- "interesting": it shows you activity which is potentially interesting for you (new questions/answers, edits by the OP)
- "housekeeping": it invites you to have a look at the actions of others to check if their edits etc. make sense.

The problem is the ratio of these two purposes. A too large percentage of the "housekeeping" can make it hard to find "interesting" content. Many users will accept a bit of "housekeeping" to help the site, but if it gets too much, checking the active question list gets boring.

Instead of removing the editor information completely, I suggest the following new features to limit the "housekeeping" to things that actually benefits the site:

1. allow a *very* limited number of users to edit without bumping to the active question list. This privilege should be *extremely* hard to get, maybe just hand-picked by mods or CMs and only a handful of users per page. This would make sure that power editors, like the OP of this question or the editor in chief of Stack Exchange, can fix minor spelling/grammar/tags without diluting the active question list (possibly with a check box if they want the edit to bump the post or not).

   (this is not a complete carte blanche, their edits will still be visible on the posts themselves, so the authors and users who visit the posts for other reasons can still scrutinise the edits, so if a users with this special privilege runs haywire, this will still be noticed)
2. give mods more differentiated tools, for example to block a user just from editing. I think currently mods might be reluctant to suspend a users who provides otherwise good content just because of bad edits. With more differentiated tools, they could more efficiently stop users who make too many bad edits.

Comment: Some great ideas here.  Thanks. re: 1--Does such a feature currently exist (privilege to edit without bumping), or would that be a new feature on SE?  re: 2--mods may not need more differentiated tools for the issue identified here.  In my own experience, it isn't so much that they're bad edits as too many for the main page to absorb without consequences.  The editors are generally well-intentioned.  A gentle reminder from a mod is usually enough to reign it in.  (cont'd)

Comment: Your suggestion 1 could be a workable solution.  It could not only solve the issue that triggered this question, it could be a way to temporarily disable bumping during large-scale retagging efforts and the like.

Comment: @fixer1234 1)  I  edited to clarify that this would be a new feature.

Comment: Option 1 would be a great solution, indeed, and a good alternative to the "*This is a minor edit*" option suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122691/422926).