# How should variants of C++ be tagged?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Should questions on Stack Overflow which are related to [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli), [c++-cx](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cx) or other C++-derived languages be tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)?

Should they be tagged with **both** [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and the derived language? Or should they be tagged **only** with the derived language?

A case in point is [How generics work in C++/CX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637514/how-generics-work-in-c-cx) . The poster asks a question about a feature that doesn't exist in C++ but that does exist in [c++-cx](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cx).

Comment: related: [Should questions be tagged with both a tag and a “sub-tag”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41206/should-questions-be-tagged-with-both-a-tag-and-a-sub-tag)

Comment: Thanks, @Bart. I think my question distinguishes itself from the previous by the relationship between the tags. No one would question that Visual Studio 2005 **is** Visual Studio. The -2005 tag is clearly subordinate to the main tag. In my case, it is an open question: is a c++-cli program written in c++? I say "no", but others might say, "yes." So I think of the secondary tags as derived from, but not an example of, the primary subject.

Comment: Sure, I agree. So "related" instead of "dupe".

Answer (score 4):

If there is syntax or entities in the question not present in plain ol' C++, then the question ***should not be tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).***

If there are no such entities then it is probably a completely general question and likely should not be tagged with the variant. Exception: if it is possible that the answers will require non-standard tools. In which case the tagging should be revised.