# Why doesn't there exist a section about Korean dramas or Asian dramas on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, tags, area-51

While I have seen all sites from Stack Exchange, I was wondering why there are no sites about Korean/Asian dramas?

First, I checked in these sites: [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com) and [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com)

And I thought there would exist a tag about Korean/Asian dramas (for example, **Korean dramas** or **Asian dramas** or something similar)

[image: Asian drama]

[image: Korean drama]

[image]
[image]

#### But, what is anime?

> a style of Japanese film and television animation, typically aimed at adults as well as children.

#### And what is K-drama?

> K-dramas are television dramas (Hangul: 드라마; RR: deurama) in the Korean language, made in South Korea

Korean dramas are popular worldwide, partially due to the spread of Korean popular culture.

> K-Drama: net-speak for a South Korean television show

[Korean drama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_drama)

Why doesn't there exist this kind of site or tag in **Movies & TV** or **Anime & Manga**?

If they are so popular on the Internet, as you can see here:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think it would be on-topic at Anime & Manga since they are only for anime and manga. But you could propose a tag for Movies & TV.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I said anime and manga because some drama are based in animes and mangas

Comment: If you have a question about a drama based on an anime, maybe you could ask it there and tag it with the title. But I don't think you can ask about a drama not based on an anime or manga.

Comment: and should I ask  about this tag in movie & tv?

Comment: Yes, you could ask your question over at [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). You can also create a tag for your question if you have 300 reputation. If you don't have 300 yet, you can ask a question about a korean drama and just use a generic tag like "drama". Someone can create a more appropriate tag for your question later.

Comment: By the way, SE tag names do not work the way you're searching for: they can't contain spaces, so there is no site that would ever have those particular tag names. M&TV *does* have a tag called [korean-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean-cinema), although there's only one question tagged with it and I don't know that it's especially relevant.

Comment: @NathanTuggy ah I did not know that but thank you for you help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's not a huge collection of existing questions about this subject that I'm aware of but it would absolutely be on topic on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com). One thing to keep in mind is that how questions are sorted (in tags) largely depends on the site and M&TV doesn't sort questions by genre (for the most part). Though there haven't necessarily been many recent discussions about it, I remember some very fraught ones from 2015 like [this one](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/the-future-of-genre-tags).

There are a few tags for genres that get used in the case that a question is actually *about* the genre but, with a [maximum of five tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34732/why-is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-tags) per question and what genre something belongs to being somewhat subjective, they don't tend to get used that way there. Tags on M&TV tend to focus on the title of the show and what the question is about - plot explanations, analysis, characters, etc...

Here's an example of a couple of questions that are on the site (found by searching for "Korean"):

- [How can Chae Young-Shin Drive at the end of Healer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38888/how-can-chae-young-shin-drive-at-the-end-of-healer)
- [What's the meaning of MC, PD, FD in Korean TV serial Running Man?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30639/whats-the-meaning-of-mc-pd-fd-in-korean-tv-serial-running-man?s=6|21.9746)

There are also several questions about Korean films.

So, if you want to ask a question about one of these TV shows or films, feel free! If there's not a title tag already existing, it's likely that someone will add it for you. If they don't, you can leave a comment asking that they do.

---

If you're asking why such a specific site doesn't already exist, it's because we tend to try to group subjects as much as we can. While we don't have a specific site for Korean Dramas or TV, they already have a home, even if they're not a very common question.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your interest in expanding our Q&A!

Tags are organic; they're created when somebody asks the first question about that subject.  So the absence of tags for these topics doesn't mean they're not welcome; it means nobody's asked about them yet (or at least not in a way that made the need for the tag obvious).

But that's fine.  You're interested in this topic, you have questions -- go ahead and ask them!  You can then request the tag; sometimes a comment suffices or sometimes you need to ask in chat or bring it up on meta.  As soon as there are questions to which the tag could be applied, the tag can be created.

Since this is probably a specialized topic for the communities you've mentioned, be sure to write (or propose) a tag wiki after the tag is created.